# Calculating the Basis of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

$$
       A= \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 0 & -1 & 7 \\
        0 & -1 & 0 & 1\\
        2 & 1 & 1 & 3 \\
        1 & 0 & -4 & 0 \end{bmatrix}
\\$$

I m not sure with the solution but is it $\{(1,0,0,-4/11 ),(0,1,0,0),(0,0,1,4/11)\} $ ?

Its not a homework

Answer (score 3):

A matrix doesn't have a basis, so the question doesn't make sense.  If you're asking about the rowspace of the matrix, to find that basis you put it in [row echelon form](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=echelon+form+of+%5B%5B1%2C0%2C-1%2C7%5D%2C%5B0%2C-1%2C0%2C1%5D%2C%5B2%2C1%2C1%2C3%5D%2C%5B1%2C0%2C-4%2C0%5D%5D), which for this matrix is the identity.  A basis is therefore $\{(1,0,0,0),(0,1,0,0),(0,0,1,0),(0,0,0,1)\}$.  What you forwarded cannot be a basis since it contains only three vectors not four.

Comment: i think i totaly get the definition "Basis" wrong